# Merge 2 arrays into empty 3rd array in C

Tags: c

I have 2 arrays:

```
array1[] = {1,2,3,4}; 
array2[] = {5,6,7,8};
```

And I try to merge them into a 3rd array:

```
merge[] = {};
```

My script currently output:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   3
>   4
>   3
>   4

Instead of:

> 1 
>   2 
>   3 
>   4 
>   5 
>   6 
>   7
>   8

Can't figure out the problem with my loop conditions:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

printf("\n\n");

int array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
int array2[] = {5,6,7,8};
int merge[] = {};
int n1, n2, n3, i;

//size of arrays
n1 = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);
n2 = sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0]);
n3 = n1 + n2;

printf("The value of n1 is %d\n", n1);
printf("sum of array1 & array2 lengths is %d\n\n", n3);


for(int i = 0 ; i < n1; i++){
    merge[i] = array1[i];
    printf("%d\n", merge[i]);

};

for(int i = n1 ; i < n3; i++){
    merge[i] = array2[i-n1];
    printf("%d\n", merge[i]);
};


printf("\n\n");
return 0;
};
```

### Update

I try to declare merge as:

```
int merge[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

This works.

The problem in the original question- declaring an empty array with no elements in it: merge[] = {}; 
but still not sure why the output was 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4.

Comment: `merge`s size is 0. You don't want an array of a size `0`. Arrays don't resize themselves for you

Comment: in fact it's depend of your OS, your achitecture, etc... In my OS, n3 is equal to 8, and merge is correctly ordered (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour, due to accessing non-existent elements of `merge`.    Change the definition of `merge` from `int merge[] = {}` which has zero elements (hence the undefined behaviour) to `int merge[sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]) + sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0])]` or (if you define AFTER the initialisation of `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`) define it as `int merge[n3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate n1, n2 & n3 then create Merge Array with n3 then you don't need to hard code the length. I have update your code as needed.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

printf("\n\n");

int array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
int array2[] = {5,6,7,8};
int n1, n2, n3, i;

//size of arrays
n1 = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);
n2 = sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0]);
n3 = n1 + n2;
int merge[n3];

printf("The value of n1 is %d\n", n1);
printf("sum of array1 & array2 lengths is %d\n\n", n3);


for(int i = 0 ; i < n1; i++){
    merge[i] = array1[i];
    printf("%d\n", merge[i]);

};

for(int i = n1 ; i < n3; i++){
    merge[i] = array2[i-n1];
    printf("%d\n", merge[i]);
};


printf("\n\n");
return 0;
};
```

I hope this is what you are expecting.